“Diamond White“
Claire Douglas, The Girls who Disappeared, 2022, p. 1

Sally’s voice was high, excitable and a little slurred as she recalled the moment Mal had bought her a Diamond White.

A group of British girls chatting away in year 1998. What in heaven could be a “Diamond White“? It’s on page 1, so no further context is available.
Thanks in advance

Did you try Googling? "A brand of white cider produced in Shepton Mallet, Somerset, England by Brookfield Drinks. It has an alcohol content of 7.5%." Wikipedia

Thank you! No, Google did not give me this results in the first three or four pages…

I found it overrun by results for "white diamond" until I used quote marks, "Diamond White", to prioritize searching as an exact phrase.

You should still consult common reference works such as Wikipedia before asking a question here.

It seems to be an English brand of hard cider. From Wikipedia:

Diamond White is a brand of white cider produced in Shepton Mallet, Somerset, England by Brookfield Drinks, who bought the brand from the Gaymer Cider Company in 2013. Like White Star, it is a cider with an alcohol content of 7.5%. It was launched by the Taunton Cider Company of Shepton Mallet, now part of Matthew Clark, in 1986, and is one of the company's major brands of cider.


Much favoured by the descendants of Hogarth's "Drunk for a penny, dead drunk for sixpence" crowd. Not the stuff you'd serve His Majesty...

It's cheap, it comes in 3 litre soda pop bottles, and you drink it in the park usually on the swings.
